# Angular: Use ng-click to auto fill/change data stored inside ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angularjs-ng-click

I am new to angular. I have a simple page with a ng-grid that displays days and times. The idea is a driver is on the page and can click for each time slot whether his is available at the time to volunteer driving (Y, or N).

Currently you can click on a box and manually edit the box. I am seeing if there is a way where you can just click on a box and have it auto switch back and forth between a "Y" and a "N", rather than being able to edit anything inside the box. Here are my files:

---

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Driver Scheduler</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <section data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <br>
        <p>Driver:
        <select ng-model="atcStatusTasks" ng-options="s.name for s in statusTaskList"></select>
         <button>Save</button></p>
         <br>
    </section>
    <section ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>

    </section>


    </body>
</html>
```

---

main.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [
        { time: "8:00am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "8:15am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "8:30am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "8:45am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "9:00am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "9:15am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "9:30am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "9:45am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "10:00am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "10:15am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "10:30am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "10:45am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "11:00am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "11:15am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "11:30am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "11:45am", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "12:00pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "12:15pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "12:30pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "12:45pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "1:00pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "1:15pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "1:30pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "1:45pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "2:00pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "2:15pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "2:30pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "2:45pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "3:00pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "3:15pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "3:30pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "3:45pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "4:00pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "4:15pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "4:30pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "4:45pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "5:00pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "5:15pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "5:30pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "5:45pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "6:00pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "6:15pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "6:30pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "6:45pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "7:00pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "7:15pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "7:30pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "7:45pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" },
        { time: "8:00pm", monday: "N", tuesday: "N", wednesday: "N", thursday: "N", friday: "N" }

    ],

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        enableCellSelection: true,
        enableCellEdit: true,
        enableRowSelection: false,
        enableSorting: false,
        columnDefs: [{ field: 'time', displayName: 'Time Slot', enableCellEdit: false }, { field: 'monday', displayName: 'Monday' }, { field: 'tuesday', displayName: 'Tuesday' }, { field: 'wednesday', displayName: 'Wednesday' }, { field: 'thursday', displayName: 'Thursday' }, { field: 'friday', displayName: 'Friday' }]
    };
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.statusTaskList = [
       { name: 'Chad Hall', value: '1' },
       { name: 'Wesley Woo', value: '2' },
       { name: 'Ariel Ayya', value: '3' },
       { name: 'Nathan Non', value: '4' },
    ];
    $scope.atcStatusTasks = $scope.statusTaskList[0]; // 0 -> Open 

});
```

---

style.css:

```
/*style.css*/
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 600px; 
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

Comment: can you make a fiiddle?

Comment: Do you want to use check box?

Comment: i'm trying to get it to work in jsfiddle. i'll keep trying. The idea is to not have checkboxes. It would just all be default to N's. Then, if you click on a N, it switches to a Y. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `ng-click` directive from your `span`

```
<span  ng-click="change()">{{val}}</span>
```

and in controller you can define function as follows

> controller

```
.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, $element)
  {
      $scope.val='N';
      $scope.change = function() {
         if($scope.val==='N')
            {$scope.val='Y';}
            else{
            $scope.val='N';}

      }

  })
```

see  [working js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/09k8f5s4/97/)

Comment: trying to get it to work. i think this is leading me the right way

Comment: you just define the scope and add the function in your controller

Comment: here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/09k8f5s4/97/
I just can't figure out how to incorporate the ng-click event into it. 
I will keep playing with it. I just can't seem to make it work. Do I need to add variables into my $scope.myData? something like: 
$scope.myData = [
        { time: "8:00am", monday: val, tuesday: val,
??????????????